# Trying to reorganize csv lat lon

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to flip the lat long in a exported csv but am having a hard time getting python to recognize the rows to reorder them. Need the below data to read W#### N#####, W#### N#### so that QGIS's WKT layer import will work correctly later after I finish the formatting for WKT using Linestring().

```
Example Data:
name,start_y,start_x,end_y,end_x
name2: 10,N 42.50105, W 122.87444, N 42.50079, W 122.74144
name3: 11,N 42.49398, W 123.47816, N 42.49453, W 123.29451
name4: 12,N 42.48980, W 123.47812, N 42.49036, W 123.29027
name5: 13,N 42.49403, W 123.20165, N 42.49411, W 123.12354
```

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
with open(mycsv.csv', 'r') as infile, open(mycsv.csv', 'a') as outfile:
        # output dict needs a list for new column ordering
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames= ['name',  'start_x', 'start_y', 'end_x', 'end_y'], extrasaction='ignore', delimiter = ',')
        # reorder the header first
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
            # writes the reordered rows to the new file
            writer.writerow(row)
```

When I use this code the csv stays the same. So I ran:

```
import sys

    f = open(sys.argv[0],'r')
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    num_cols = len(next(reader)) # Read first line and count columns
    print(num_cols)
```

and it tells me that it's only counting 1 column so it makes sense that the first formula isn't working because it's not reading the csv in separate columns, but one single line. What am I missing? Python 3.9 is what I'm using. Thanks in advance!

ps, this is my first python program and I have no formal coding education so please excuse any rookie mistakes

Comment: Your csv has 5 headers but only 3 columns in the data, but you say it only counted one column, so make sure you are giving us the *exact* content of the input file.

Comment: Apologies, there were some "," missing from the example data set I provided. This is now how the data looks at this point in the python. Headers should match what I understand to be columns now.

Comment: Best not to manually type your test input and code, but cut and paste your exact data/code reproducing your problem.  For example, the indentation is wrong and there are missing single quotes in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `input.csv`:

```
name,start_y,start_x,end_y,end_x
name2: 10,N 42.50105, W 122.87444, N 42.50079, W 122.74144
name3: 11,N 42.49398, W 123.47816, N 42.49453, W 123.29451
name4: 12,N 42.48980, W 123.47812, N 42.49036, W 123.29027
name5: 13,N 42.49403, W 123.20165, N 42.49411, W 123.12354
```

Your code basically works.  I removed some extra parameters not needed, used `'w'` for writing and added `newline=''` as required in the `csv` module documentation, though, and make sure not to read/write the same file.

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames= ['name', 'start_x', 'start_y', 'end_x', 'end_y'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

output.csv:

```
name,start_x,start_y,end_x,end_y
name2: 10, W 122.87444,N 42.50105, W 122.74144, N 42.50079
name3: 11, W 123.47816,N 42.49398, W 123.29451, N 42.49453
name4: 12, W 123.47812,N 42.48980, W 123.29027, N 42.49036
name5: 13, W 123.20165,N 42.49403, W 123.12354, N 42.49411
```

If you *do* want to re-write the original file, then you must read all the lines into memory, *then* write them back out, but that's risky until you are sure the code is correct.

```py
import csv

with open('mycsv.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(infile))

with open('mycsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames= ['name', 'start_x', 'start_y', 'end_x', 'end_y'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows) # note plural writerows to re-write all data
```

Comment: newline = ''  and "rows" seems to be what I was missing. This works perfect now. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as written for me (once I corrected the quotation marks). But note that you are opening the same file for output (in append mode) and input. Opening the same file twice is generally a bad idea that may work differently on different systems, but in this case it works for me; the new data is appended to the end of the file. Perhaps it's not working that way on your system, or perhaps the fact that the start of the file stays the same is why you think it's not working? You might want to write the reordered rows to a different file instead.

Your code on your sample data results in `mycsv.csv` looking like this:

```
name,start_y,start_x,end_y,end_x
name2: 10,N 42.50105, W 122.87444, N 42.50079, W 122.74144
name3: 11,N 42.49398, W 123.47816, N 42.49453, W 123.29451
name4: 12,N 42.48980, W 123.47812, N 42.49036, W 123.29027
name5: 13,N 42.49403, W 123.20165, N 42.49411, W 123.12354
name,start_x,start_y,end_x,end_y
name2: 10, W 122.87444,N 42.50105, W 122.74144, N 42.50079
name3: 11, W 123.47816,N 42.49398, W 123.29451, N 42.49453
name4: 12, W 123.47812,N 42.48980, W 123.29027, N 42.49036
name5: 13, W 123.20165,N 42.49403, W 123.12354, N 42.49411
```

Comment: The append was a good catch too that I would have run into as soon as I solved the first issue. I never made it that far but thank you for taking the time to point that out too!